# How do I fix a 403 using JwtBearerAuthentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid, jwt

I'm trying to understand how to delve into the automagic I get when I configure the hell out of asp.net. I'm currently translating a small api from asp.net web-api 2 to asp.net core. I'm not sure where the 403 is coming from in this configuration or how to fix it. Right now the majority of the api endpoint just need a valid token and do not need to check for any specific claim in the token. So for all my authenticated controllers I get a 403 response that should be a 200, when using a valid bearer token. Also right now I use asymmetric keys with Auth0 as the provider.

Startup.cs configure method I'm using to validate the JWT bearer tokens.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        //Middleware added here order matters

        //TODO formatter settings https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/formatting.html

        //samples to check
        //https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/webapi-owin
        //https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-webapi-rs256
        var options = new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Audience = Configuration["auth0:clientId"]
            ,Authority = $"https://{Configuration["auth0:domain"]}/"
            ,Events = new JwtBearerEvents() // just a pass through to log events
        };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);
        // Very hacky to catch invaild tokens https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/issues/191
        // issue says the need for the required hack is fixed but it's been still happening. Issue about the fix https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/411
        app.Use(next => async context => {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch
            {
                // If the headers have already been sent, you can't replace the status code.
                // In this case, throw an exception to close the connection.
                if (context.Response.HasStarted)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        });
        app.UseMvc();

        // TODO global exception handling https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6398
        app.UseSwaggerGen();
        app.UseSwaggerUi();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems your token middleware is not executed to validate incoming requests. 
Try setting the token middleware to run automaticly.

```
    var options = new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        //other configurations..
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    };
```

You can also use attributes to specify the authentication scheme in the controllers.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "MyAuthenticationScheme")]
```

Read more about it here: [Limiting identity by scheme](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme.html)

Comment: AutomaticAuthenticate = true; is the default

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the policy in the ConfigureServices section. The simplest policy is all I need at the moment.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(c =>
        {
            // TODO implement this abstract class c.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionFilterAttribute));
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            c.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            c.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelFilter));
        });
```